# Invalid SOS number - California EDD Number Registration

Tags: incorporation, corporate-tax-laws

I'm trying to get an EDD (employment development department) number to file with payroll, and it's asking me for my Secretary of State Identification number.

I have the number, but the site isn't letting me submit, saying "Invalid SOS."

Answer (score -2):

TL;DR put a C at the beginning

If you are an LLC, your number is a 12-digit number starting with 19 or 20

If you are a corporation, your number is a 7-digit number starting with a C

No one tells you about the C

Source: https://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/cbs-field-status-definitions